# TransactionScope not rolling back although no complete() is called

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm using TransactionScope to rollback a transaction that fail

```
bool errorReported = false;
Action<ImportErrorLog> newErrorCallback = e =>
{
    errorReported = true;
    errorCallback(e);
};

using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    foreach (ImportTaskDefinition task in taskDefinition)
    {
        loader.Load(streamFile, newErrorCallback, task.DestinationTable, ProcessingTaskId);
    }
    if (!errorReported)
        transaction.Complete();
}
```

I'm sure there is no TransactionScope started ahead or after this code.
I'm using entity framework to insert in my DB.

Regardless the state of `errorReported` the transaction is never rolled back in case of error.

What am I missing ?

Comment: If you decide you want that block to be its own transaction, independent of the ambient transaction, you can do `new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TransactionScope` sets `Transaction.Current`. That's all it does. Anything that wants to be transacted must look at that property.

I believe EF does so each time the connection is opened for any reason. Probably, your connection is already open when the scope is installed.

Open the connection inside of the scope or enlist manually.

EF has another nasty "design decision": By default it opens a new connection for each query. That causes distributed transactions in a non-deterministic way. Be sure to avoid that.

Comment: Maybe the dependency injection I use to load my factories could be the root of the problem then...Searching in this directing, thank you :)